# Adding x to each element of a list without creating a new list

Tags: python, list, loops, element

How can I add a constant (ie 10) to a list without creating a new list?
For example,

```
list = [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

How can I overwrite the elements in this list without creating another list (append method)? I understand that there is a map lambda method. Any way to go about by using a for loop?

When `x = 10`, expected final output should be

```
list = [12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: You could use a for comprehension and assign the result to the same variable:
`list = [item + 10 for item in list]`

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 10
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    list[i] = list[i] + x
```

I kept the variable name as list, but I recommend you don't use built-in names as names for your variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can for sure use the map function in Python as follows. I changed your list name to list1 to not confuse it with the datatype.

```
list1 = [2,4,6,8]
print(list(map(lambda x : x+10, list1)))
```

Comment: Could be even nicer with a variable instead of "10"

Comment: `list()` is a constructor, creating a new list. `-1`

Answer (score 0):

@Jax Teller 's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895247/913098) is the standard.

Here is a generator, not changing the original, but instead yielding mapped values

Also, using the word `list` isn't good, because it is a Python construct. Use something else instead like `my_list`

```
my_list = [2,4,6,8]
val = 10
gen = (val + e for e in my_list)
```

This is actually the same as `map`.
Just notice you can't use `list(gen)` because it would create a new list, not just iterate.